# Height argument for post critically finite $z^2+c$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

I know that if we require $c$ to be rational the only post-critically finite maps of the form $z^2+c$ have $c = 0$ or $c=-1$. Is there a height argument for why this is true? It seems there must be, as heights are closely related to preperiodic points. I would also be interested in real-values or complex values and the associated proofs.

Comment: In complex dynamics, we say that map is *post-critically finite* the orbit of every critical point contains finitely many points. There are infinitely many values of $c\in\mathbb C$ for which this is the case. Is there any chance you're studying dynamics in the context of a finite field?

Comment: Sorry Mark, I meant to say rational numbers. I would also be curious to see if there are more post-critically finite real values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about canonical heights? If not, first look them up, then here's some material. Let $K$ be a number field and $f(z)\in K(z)$ a polynomial of degree $d\ge2$. The *critical height of $f$* is
$$
h^{\text{crit}}(f) = \sum_{\alpha\in\operatorname{Crit}(f)} \hat h_f(\alpha). 
$$
A fairly recent theorem of Patrick Ingram says that
$$
h^{\text{crit}}(f) = h(f) +O(1),
$$
where the $O(1)$ depends only on $d$. (Here $h(f)$ is the height of $f$ in the moduli space of maps of degree $d$. For $f_c(z)=z^2+c$, you can just take $h(f_c)=h(c)$. In particular, $$ \text{$f$ is PCF}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad h^{\text{crit}}(f)=0. $$
Hence
$$ \text{$f$ is PCF}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \text{$h(f)$ is bounded.} $$

There was earlier work proving this for just polynomials, and earlier works proving somewhat more directly (but still using heights) that the set of PCF maps is a set of bounded height. But you can get those from the references in Ingram's papers:

- Ingram, Patrick, The critical height is a moduli height, *Duke Math. J.* **167** (2018), 1311-1346
- Ingram, Patrick, A finiteness result for post-critically finite polynomials, *Int. Math. Res. Not. IMRN* **3** (2012), 524-543